# How to know what memory zones are writable

Tags: memory, memory-management, ida, writable

I want to know how to know what memory zones are flagged as writable while I am debugging a process.

So, I put a breackpoint in the code and I want to know in that moment what memory zone is writable. How can I do it? I'm using IDA Pro.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy:

View > Open Subview > Segments (or Shift+F7)

[image: Segments IDA PRO]